# forcasting time series(seasonality & trend plot)

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a problem that search alot but now I'm confused what I must do!! maybe you say that alot of page explain ways but I don't understand till now!
I have some data that come end of every half hour and I must predict it before it received at begin of half hour, I suppose this data is trend and seasonality with period one week. so I need a way that at first time it just estimate, then predict for every half hour without history till a week spend and after this week I have history for each slot(half hour). I want improve my forecasting with data received.

thanks

Comment: If data in a week have similar value according to seanonality, average of data from beging of the week to latest1 data may be good estimate for next data.

Comment: yes, I used this way. but I want several ways to compare. same as "Holt-Winters additive method" at https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/5 , but I don't know how use them!